# For an associated linear representation of a $FG - $module are all linear transformations bijections?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $FG$ be a group ring and $V$ an $FG-$module. We know that $V$ affords a linear representation $\phi: G \rightarrow GL(V).$ My question is $\forall g \in G,$ is $\phi(g)$ a bijection? Each $\phi(g)$ is a linear transformation from $V$ to $V$ and we know that each $g \in G$ has an inverse. Thus, $(g^{-1}g) \cdot v = (id) \cdot v.$ Is $\phi(id)$ the identity map from $V$ to $V?$ If this is the case then I suppose I am correct but are there linear representations where $\phi(id_G) \neq $ identity map on $V?$

Comment: Sorry isn't $\mathbb{Z}_n$ an additive group so its identity is 0?

Comment: It is usually the case (by definition) a representation $\phi$ has its image in ${\rm GL}(V)$, the group of invertible linear transformations on $V,$ so all transformations in the image are bijections.  There are sometimes situations  when it is helpful to drop this requirement ( for example if there is a non-identity  idempotent in ${\rm End}_{G}(V)).$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\phi(id_G)$ must be the identity on $V$; indeed, a representation is the same thing as a group homomorphism $G\to GL(V)$, and group homomorphisms preserve the neutral element. But here, defining a representation as a group homomorphism is really putting the cart before the horses : $GL(V)$ as the group of linear bijections $V\to V$, if we use this definition we are already assuming that $\phi(g)$ is a bijection for all $g$. But if you define a representation with the requirement that $\phi(id)$ is the identity on $V$ and $\phi(g\cdot g')=\phi(g)\circ \phi(g')$, then your proof that every $\phi(g)$ is a bijection is correct. This alternative definition amounts to saying that a representation is a *monoid* morphism $G\to End(V)$, and then the proof amounts to noting that since $G$ is a group, it must factor through the group of invertible transformations $GL(V)$ (which we can see as a submonoid of $End(V)$.

You can't prove that $\phi(id)$ is the identity only with the assumption that $\phi(g\cdot g')=\phi(g)\circ \phi(g')$; for example, $\phi(g)=0$ for all $g$ satisfies the last requirement.

If you prefer to see the representation as an $FG$-module, then you can use the fact that $id_{G}$ is a multiplicative unit for the group ring, and it must act trivially for any module.

Comment: I see! Thank you  for your response. Would I be correct in saying that for every image of $g$ in $G \rightarrow GL(V)$ is a bijection then?

Comment: That's a bit awkward. I'll edit my answer.